# Can I set properties toward beans in an imported library?

Tags: java, micronaut

I have a main Micronaut service. I also have a library project which houses some beans. One such bean (reduced) is:

```
@Singleton
public class Testo {
    @Value("${testo}")
    public int testo;
}
```

I am successfully "importing" this bean and `@Inject`ing it as described in the documentation. However, I cannot for the life of me set this "testo" property from the main service. System properties, Environment variables, PropertyResource files (application.yml), at any level -> nothing works.

I check this through both a printout of the variable in the terminal, or debugging using IDEA.

Is it possible to set properties of beans that are housed in a library project?

Micronaut v3.1.3
Java 11

Comment: "Is it possible to set properties of beans that are housed in a library project?" - The answer is "yes" but it isn't clear from your description why that isn't working for you.  You can initialize that with any of the sources you mentioned (system properties, environment variables, property resource files, and others).  If you can share a simple project which demonstrates the behavior, that would likely be trivial to troubleshoot.

Comment: See docs at https://docs.micronaut.io/3.1.3/guide/#infoEndpoint which mention setting `endpoints.info.git.location`.  That config value you will affect the value passed into the `GitInfoSource` constructor defined at https://github.com/micronaut-projects/micronaut-core/blob/afaeae53e8e8805483ae0a0a82b3d6f0c92f6a6a/management/src/main/java/io/micronaut/management/endpoint/info/source/GitInfoSource.java#L56.  That is an example of setting a `@Value` property in your app and using it to initialize a value in a bean that is provided by a library (`GitInfoSource`).  I hope that is helpful.

Answer (score 0):

> Is it possible to set properties of beans that are housed in a library
> project?

It is.  If you have `@Value("${some.config.value}")` on a property in a bean that is defined in your application or a bean that is defined in a properly compiled Micronaut bean provided by a library, then you can provide a value for `some.config.value` through any of the supported config source mechanism and that value will be used to initialize the property marked with `@Value`.

Of course that only works if the bean is being managed by the Micronaut context.  If you are doing something like `new Testo()` then the `@Value` annotation will have no effect.